# Why does pandas writes the escapechar at this position in my CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following data:

```
data_list = ["\"TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA\"", "\"\"\"TUTU,ROOT\"\"\""]
```

It is transformed into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data_list)
print(df)

                         0
0  "TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA"
1          """TUTU,ROOT""
```

When writing the dataframe as a csv, without any quoting configuration, I get the following result:

```
with open("test_quote_normal", "w") as w:
    df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False)
```

-> result output

```
"""TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA"""

"""""""TUTU,ROOT"""""""
```

Every quotes have been quoted, which is not something I want.

So i tried to prevent this with the following configuration:

```
with open("test_quote_none", "w") as w:
    df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False,
              quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=',')
```

-> result output

```
"TOTO TITI TATA,,TAGADA"

"""TUTU,,ROOT"""
```

The quotes are correct, but for a reason I do not understand, the escape char has been inserted in  the data itself.

Specifying the sep value has no effect:

```
with open("test_quote_none", "w") as w:
    df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False,
              quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=',', sep= ",")
```

Why does pandas inserts the escape char in the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"` and `,` are both special characters by default in csv format

`"` is used when `,` is there between a data. That time the data is escaped by quotes to tell that it should be a single data.

whereas, `,` is the default seperator for distinguishing between data.

Since you are using both of them in your data, that's why you are having such a hard time debugging it

**First snippet**

```
with open("test_quote_normal", "w") as w:
    df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False)
```

If the data still has `"`, as per csv conventions, it should also be escaped which was causing multiple `"` in your first scenario

**Second snippet**

```
with open("test_quote_none", "w") as w:
    df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False,
              quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=',')
```

Using the `quoting` parameter, you are telling that you don't indent quotes to protect the `,` character. So the `,` inside your data is being treated as a separator causing the escape character to come between them

For more clarity, you can see the output of these snippets

```
with open("temp.csv", "w") as w:
    ...:     df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False, quotechar='@')
```

Output

```
@"TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA"@
@"""TUTU,ROOT"""@
```

In this, we are changing the `quotechar` to become `@`, that's why, instead of using `"` for protecting `,`, this time `@` is being used to escape data with `,` inside them

```
with open("temp.csv", "w") as w:
    ...:     df.to_csv(w, index=False, header=False, escapechar='@', doublequote=False)
```

Output

```
"@"TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA@""
"@"@"@"TUTU,ROOT@"@"@""
```

In this, the quotechar is still the same, but for escaping them, we are changing it to `@` for clarity, this time you can see the difference on `quotechar` and `escapechar`

I hope this helps your question

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect?

```
print(df.to_csv(index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep= "@"))

"TOTO TITI TATA,TAGADA"
"""TUTU,ROOT"""
```